# Search a preprocessed text with online queries

Tags: optimization, strings, online-algorithms

We're given a fixed text, and we are presented with a series of online queries of patterns. For each query, the goal is to answer if the pattern exists in the text. Each pattern is a string, and we want to know if it appears as a substring of the text. The text can be preprocessed.

What's the optimal way to solve this?

Comment: I'm not an expert, but I'd look at the algorithms based on suffix arrays.

Answer (score 4):

By building a [suffix trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_tree).

If you wish to preprocess the search query, then there is this algorithm by [Boyer–Moore](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore_string_search_algorithm), whose complexity is believed to be linear after applying Galil Rule (details in the same page).

Other than that, if you can preprocess the whole text before hand and construct a Suffix Trie, then you can achieve many things. But the main limitation is it requires a lot of space.

See [Suffix Trees](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~ckingsf/bioinfo-lectures/suffixtrees.pdf) and the [lecture from MIT](http://courses.csail.mit.edu/6.851/spring12/scribe/lec16.pdf) ([Complete List](http://courses.csail.mit.edu/6.851/spring12/lectures/))

See also Popular [String searching algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_searching_algorithm).